# VueJs access data in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I find myself facing a problem.
I need to retrieve a parameter in the url to display data dynamically but I can't find the solution.

what parameter must enter in state.event.aftermovies [] to have access to the id of my object.

If anyone has a solution, thanks

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="container text-center">
      <div>
        <h1>{{ aftermovie.id }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ aftermovie.name }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ aftermovie.slug }}</h1>
        <h1>{{ aftermovie.video }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  async fetch({ store, error, params }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch('fetchEvent', params.id)
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch event #' + params.id,
      })
    }
  },

  //Here is my problem
  computed: mapState({
    aftermovie: (state) => state.event.aftermovies[??????????????????]
  }),
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.aftermovie.name
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and I would like to access the id of my object

```js
event:Object
address:"Belgium"
aftermovies:Array[1]
0:Object
event_id:1
festival_id:""
id:4
name:"reverze 2020"
slug:"reverze-2020"
```

what is the right way ??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `aftermovies` is an array containing objects like:

```
aftermovies: [{
  event_id:1,
  festival_id:"",
  id:4,
  name:"reverze 2020",
  slug:"reverze-2020"
}]
```

you could do something like `aftermovies[0].id`

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yjay/1ed3qxhf/11/)